# How to deal with terraform modules that depends on other modules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have this problem. I am trying to create a `network` and `subnetworks` in `gcp` and I am using modules to do so.

So my directory structure looks like below:

```
modules
  network
     main.tf
     variables.tf
  subnetworks
     main.tf
     variables.tf
main.tf
terraform.tfvars
variables.tf
```

The folders inside the `module` where I have put the modules as the name suggests.

And `main.tf` inside the `network` looks like this:

```
# module to create the subnet
resource "google_compute_network" "network" {
  name                    = var.network_name
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}
```

And the `main.tf` inside the `subnetworks` looks like this:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "public-subnetwork" {
  network          = // how to refer the network name here?
  ...
}
```

in normal scenarios when we have a one single terraform file for every resource (when we don't use modules), it would look like this:

```
# create vpc
resource "google_compute_network" "kubernetes-vpc" {
  name                    = "kubernetes-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "master-sub" {
  network       = google_compute_network.kubernetes-vpc.name
  ...
}
```

We can directly call the `google_compute_network.kubernetes-vpc.name` for the value of `network` when creating the `google_compute_subnetwork`. But now since I am using modules, how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `outputs.tf` file in the `network`.

Inside the `outputs.tf` file you can declare a resource like this.

```
output "google_compute_network_name" {
  description = "The name of the network"
  value       = google_compute_network.network.name
}
```

Now inside the `subnetwork` module you can use a standard variable to receive the value of the network name.

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "public-subnetwork" {
  // receive network name as variable
  network          = var.network_name
  ...
}
```

And where you use the modules `network` and `subnetworks` in `main.tf`, from the roof folder (I assume) you can pass the `output` variable from module `network` to the `subnetwork` module.

Example:

```
module "root_network" {
 source = "./modules/network"
}

module "subnetwork" {
 source = "./modules/subnetworks"
 // input variable for subnetwork from the output of the network
 network_name = module.root_network.google_compute_network_name
}
```

If you want to read more about output variables you can find the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html).

Comment: Thank you, the `outputs.tf` inside the `network` module, why do you put it as a separate file? We use it inside the `main.tf` inside the `network` module too right? I thought putting `outputs.tf` in a separate file wouldn't work.

Comment: Usually is a best practice to place the variables exported by a module in a separate outputs.tf file to have a clear overview over what internal resources created by the module that are intended to be used by other external modules. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. And one small question, how can I do the same for the backend `terraform` file where I try to set a remote bucket to store the state. I need this to be a separate file from the `main.tf` in `root` directory. Is it possible? and if so, when we apply `terraform  apply` how terraform know to  execute the file with backend configurations first and then execute the `main.tf` to create resources?

Comment: Hello, I believe you cannot use variable or interpolation in the `backend` declaration.
Something that might help you is `terraform workspaces`, you can find documentation  here https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html .